# Python application freezes, only CTRL-C helps

Tags: python, websocket, gevent

I have a Python app that uses websockets and gevent. It's quite a big application in my personal experience.

I've encountered a problem with it: when I run it on Windows (with 'pipenv run python myapp'), it can (suddenly but very rarily) freeze, and stop accepting messages. If I then enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in cmd, it starts reacting to all the messages, that were issued when it was hanging.

I understand, that it might block somewhere, but I don't know how to debug theses types of errors, because I don't see anything in the code, that could do it. And it happens very rarily on completely different stages of the application's runtime.

What is the best way to debug it? And to actually see what goes behind the scenes? My logs show no indication of a problem.

Could it be an error with cmd and not my app?

Comment: These problems are hard to debug. The first thing I would try is to reduce the program to a minimal version that still exemplifies the same behavior. Maybe the problem is clear by then. If not I would craft some usual culprits (XMAS, NULL, ACK, FIN, RST TCP probes,  UDP probes, general spam, malformed payloads, payloads with unexpected charsets, ...) with `scapy` and see if I can trigger the problem somehow.

Comment: You could also log all the network traffic with a tool like Wireshark and wait for your program to freeze, then analyze the traffic. Maybe it's not even a networking problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be as simple as adding timeouts to some of your spawns or gevent calls.  Gevent is still single threaded, and so if an IO bound resource hangs, it can't context switch until it's been received.  Setting a timeout might help bypass these issues and move your app forward?